How to pick an actor or volume using vtk.js?
I tried to find examples of PropPicker in vtk.js documentation, but I think it doesn’t exist. I try  to import the module to but I get a not found error.
'@kitware/vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Core/PropPicker';
First, I tried to use cellPicker, but I needed to get all the objects, not just a cell.
const picker = vtkCellPicker.newInstance();
 picker.setPickFromList(1);
 picker.setTolerance(0);
 picker.initializePickList();
 picker.addPickList(actorMainAfter);

 renderWindow.getInteractor().onRightButtonPress((callData) => {
 const pos = callData.position;
 const point = [pos.x, pos.y, 0.0];

 console.log(`Pick at: ${point}`);
 picker.pick(point, rendererAfter);
 const pickedCellId = picker.getCellId();
 console.log('Picked cell: ', pickedCellId);
 renderWindow.render();
});

Does exist an equivalence of PropPicker in vtk.js?
Or does a PropPicker exist, and I didn’t find it?

There seems to be no PropPicker. However, there is Picker which can pick vtkProp3D instances. Is this what you are looking for?

On a side note, discourse would be lovely place to ask questions related to vtk
